How Do I Pass Data From PowerShell script to Windows Command
I need to modify the command file startup for a site written in Micro Focus COBOL to access an Azure key vault.  I wrote a PowerShell script to access the key vault - I need to pass back to the command file data which the command file uses to set environmant variables.  I don't want to pass a variable at the Machine level - that will defeat the purpose of using a key vault.  How do I send a string variable back to the command file?
I tried to set an environment variable in PowerShell that was non-transitory at the Process level - hoping it would be recognized by the Windows command file that called it.  The varaible was not recognized after coming back from PowerShell.
the startup command file
ECHO SETTING ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC VARIABLES
SET REGION_NAME=theRegion

powershell.exe -File "C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1"

SET FIRST_ENV_VAR=DSN=DataSet;UID=UserID;PWD=%FromPowerShell%
...
SET SHAREDFILE_LOCATION=\\theServer\theFolder
ECHO DONE SETTING ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC VARIABLES

the powershell script
ECHO 'SETTING ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC VARIABLES - PowerShell'

$Url = "https://lookupdv.site.org/API.KeyVault"
$JSON = "application/json"
$Body = @{
    URI = "KeyName"
    secretname = "UserID"
}
$Password = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -ContentType $JSON -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json)

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FromPowerShell', $Password, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)

ECHO 'DONE SETTING ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC VARIABLES - PowerShell'

this doesn't work
should I change the Set command to target User instead of Process?

The environment that gets created on the start of powershell.exe -File "..." is lost when the execution of the powershell script ends.

You might look at: How to set command output as env. variable in windows cmd?  or How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file



As Luuk notes, a child process cannot modify its parent process' environment, so any process-level environment changes made by the powershell.exe child process are invariably lost when control returns to the caller (your batch file).

However, given that you know what process-level environment variable your PowerShell script sets, you can call powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, in a manner that echoes (outputs) that variable('s value), via its stdout stream, allowing your batch file to capture it via a for /f statement; for that, you must use the -Command rather than the -File parameter; -Command allows you to pass a piece of PowerShell code.


Here's a batch-file fragment that illustrates the approach.
Note that it requires no changes to your C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1 script, because it is the piece of PowerShell code passed to -Command that ensures that the environment-variable value of interest is output:
:: ...

:: Define the PowerShell command line that calls the PowerShell script
:: and then echoes the "FromPowerShell" environment variable that was set
:: in the script.
set pscmd=powershell.exe -Command "C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1 >$null; $env:FromPowerShell"

:: Invoke the PowerShell command line, and save its only output line in a
:: variable (for the current process.)
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%pscmd%`) do set "FromPowerShell=%%i"

:: %FromPowerShell% now contains the value of interest.

:: ...

Note:

>$null above suppresses the .ps1 scripts success (stdout) output (your status messages), so that the -Command invocation only outputs the environment-variable value, and nothing else.

If you still want to see that output, you have to re-route it to stderr, by defining the PowerShell command line as follows:
set pscmd=powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "[Console]::Error.WriteLine((C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1) -join [char] 10); $env:FromPowerShell"




Note:

It follows from the above that an alternative is to modify your .ps1 file in the following manner:

Make it output the environment-variable value.

Make sure that status messages printed by the script use [Console]::Error.WriteLine() rather than echo (aka Write-Output), i.e. that the status messages do not "pollute" the success output stream and therefore stdout.

With this approach, there's not even a strict need to set an environment-variable value in your PowerShell script: simply output the value of interest directly.



You can then invoke your .ps1 file with a -File PowerShell CLI call, as before.



Both solutions assume that only one value of interest is to be communicated to the batch file.

To support multiple ones, you could make your .ps1 script output name-value pairs that you can pass to set in the calling batch file, e.g., output 'FOO=BAR' and 'BAZ=QUX' from your PowerShell script, and modify the set command in for /f loop in the batch file to set "%%i", as shown below.

Multi-value example:

Sample C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1 content:
# Print status messages to stderr, to avoid polluting
# stdout.
[Console]::Error.WriteLine('Outputting name-value pairs.')

# Output name-value pairs, to be set as environment variables
# by the batch file.
'FOO=BAR'
'BAZ=QUX'


Sample batch-file content:
 @echo off & setlocal
 :: Remove `& setlocal` if you want to variables set by this
 :: batch file to persist in a `cmd.exe` session.

 :: Define the PowerShell command line that calls the .ps1 script
 set pscmd=powershell.exe -noprofile -File C:\Util\CallAzure.Ps1

 :: Invoke the PowerShell command line, and pass the name-value
 :: pairs to `set`, which defines them as process-level 
 :: environment variables.
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%pscmd%`) do set "%%i"

 :: Echo the resulting variables for diagnostic purposes.
 echo [%FOO%]
 echo [%BAZ%]




Cmd's "for" can set a variable as the output of a command.  Double up on the %'s in a .bat file.
echo echo hi > script.ps1
for /f %i in ('powershell -file script.ps1') do set a=%i
echo %a%

hi

